# How to add or edit to a client side json file from Angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I am working with Angular 8. I have 2 JSON files on the client-side which are basically an array of JSON objects, from where I read and use in my component. I want to **add (or edit)** an object in those JSON files using angular only(without sending it to backend) and then make sure component is able to use it. Is it possible through angular? Or will I have to use a typescript file and store all information there?

Comment: Use LocalStorage or IndexDB for doing crud operation on the client side.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot But will my changes persist even after I restart the angular server?

Comment: Yes it stored against your URL, it means localhost:4200. In case URL change your data will not be accessible from new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do file operation only using Angular framework.
You can use `localStorage` or `in-memory-db` to do that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api

[Angular doc for in memory db](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)